# R data frame equivalence of SQL join and select

Tags: sql, r

Suppose I have 2 data frames A and B that both have c1, c2, c3 as columns

I wish to get a equivalent of

```
SELECT A.C1 AS "C1", A.C2 AS "C2", (A.C3 - B.C3) AS "C3"
FROM A
JOIN B
ON (A.C1 = B.C1) AND (A.C2 = B.C2);
```

How do I perform the same operation in R without using for-loop?

Edit:add example

```
A
c1, c2, c3
1, 1, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 2, 5
2, 1, 5

B
c1, c2, c3
1, 1, 2
1, 2, 4
2, 1, 8
```

should produce

```
c1, c2, c3
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 1
2, 1, -3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of possible answers here, but here's one (of the many) using just standard/base functions:

```
> foo <- merge(x = A, y = B, by.x = c("c1", "c2"), by.y = c("c1", "c2"))
> foo$c3 <- foo$c3.x - foo$c3.y
> foo <- foo[c("c1", "c2", "c3")]
```

Generally speaking, `merge(...)` is the function you seek to replicate SQL-like joins.

Also consider using R packages that permit use of SQL directly on data frames, e.g. the [sqldf](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) package.

Comment: Also, worth noting since you mentioned the dreaded words "for loop": try to make your arithmetic operations vectorized in R, your code will be much faster, more readable, and you'll be able to focus more on your problem rather than the logistics of dealing with iterators/loops/etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `data.table` alternative.

```
A = read.table(text="c1, c2, c3
1, 1, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 2, 5
2, 1, 5", header=T, sep=",")

B = read.table(text="c1, c2, c3
1, 1, 2
1, 2, 4
2, 1, 8", header=T, sep=",")

setDT(A); setDT(B) # convert data frames to data tables
setkey(A, c1, c2) # key columns c1, c2 for "joining"
new_dt <- A[B][,list(c1,    # the operation
                     c2,
                     c3 = c3-i.c3)]
new_dt

# you get
   c1 c2 c3
1:  1  1  1
2:  1  2  0
3:  1  2  1
4:  2  1 -3
```

Comment: You can do the column subset in `j` directly. `A[B, list(c1,c2,c3=c3-i.c3)]`.

Comment: No worries. The advantage is that the other columns are never materialised - hence memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution using sqldf:

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
rs <- sqldf("select a.c1, a.c2, (a.c3 - b.c3) as c3
                from a
                join b
                on a.c1 = b.c1 and a.c2 = b.c2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` possibility

```
left_join(A, B, c("c1", "c2")) %>% transmute(c1, c2, c3 = c3.x - c3.y)
#   c1 c2 c3
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  1  2  0
# 3  1  2  1
# 4  2  1 -3
```

Comment: Even better!  Thanks a lot